# MySQL Query Problem

Tags: php, sql, mysql, arrays, foreach

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT id, retailerName, savingsDetails
FROM coupons
WHERE zone =  '1';
```

When I run it in phpMyAdmin, I get back a tidy list of the rows that match my value for `zone`.

Assume that SQL code is `$gotRows`. I try to do `mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($gotRows))`, but for some reason it only creates a 1x3 array, rather than (in this case) 17x3. That is, there is only one entry in the array rather than the 17 that should be.

When I try to do:

```
foreach($resultOfThat as $foo)
{
    echo $foo;
}
```

It behaves strangely, giving me output similar to this (and only one iteration runs since there is only one entry in the array):

```
 33foofoobarbar
```

Where id = 3, retailerName = foo, and savingsDetails = bar. As in, trying to loop the array will just give me double results of each part of it, similar to how I described.

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Hey, don't you already know how to handle SQL query? Like in this question: [Reading only one column from SQL output as a numerical array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038193/reading-only-one-column-from-sql-output-as-a-numerical-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

[`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) returns a **single** row as a array. use a loop to retrieve all the results optionally storing them in a array:

```
$arr = array();
$q = mysql_query($gotRows);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
    $arr[] = $row;
}
//$arr now holds the 17x3 result set
var_dump($arr);
```

Also, the rows them self are arrays, to index the first column, `echo $row[0]`. To fetch the results as a associative array, see Patrik's answer.

Comment: I was downvoted without a comment too. Gotta love that behaviour

Answer (score 1):

The method ([`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)) you are using requires a reference to a run query, ie:

```
$queryCursor = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryCursor))
{
  // Do your thing with $row
}
```

It also returns "the next row", from the result set, not the entire result.

The reason you get duplicate entries is that mysql_fetch_array takes a secondary parameter that describes whether the method should return numeric, associative, or both types in the row for each column. The default is to return BOTH numeric and associative entries for each column.

If you only want numeric or associative columns, either specify the last parameter as `MYSQL_ASSOC` or use a different function, such as [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).

As a final note, I would highly recommend that you use some kind of DBAL (DataBase Abstraction Layer), and optionally an ORM (Object Relational Mapper) since the built in library requires a lot of boiler plate code whenever you want to interact with the database. It also makes it harder, or at least requires you to do more coding, when you want to setup more advanced stuff such as shared versus multiple connections, delegating CRUD queries to a specific connection (so it can later be replicated to slave databases) etc. DBAL's often has this built in as features.
An ORM takes care of converting the relational representation into your object oriented representation transparently, allowing you to focus on your application instead of building mapper code.

Libraries that come to mind are [Zend_Db](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html) and [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/). There are a lot of other libraries out there, I'd recommend you to find one that is actively maintained that fits your programming style.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you debug:

```
$result = mysql_query($gotRows);
if (!$result) {
  die(mysql_error());
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  var_dump($row);
}
```